# Plugin taking variable as string literal

Tags: azure-devops

I have a script that sets a value on a variable:

```
$x = netlify sites:list --json
$y = $x | ConvertFrom-Json

$site = $y | where { $_.name -eq "testsiteaa" }
$siteId = $site.id

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=netlifySiteId]$siteId"
```

In a follow up task:

```
Write-Host "Set environment variable to $env:netlifySiteId"
```

> 2021-04-23T07:51:46.9329269Z Set environment variable to 20547918-b452-4859-9a2f-**

So far so good.

Then I use the [Netlify plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aliencube.netlify-cli-extensions) to deploy my artifact on the site:

```
    steps:
- task: aliencube.netlify-cli-extensions.deploy-task.deploy@1
  displayName: 'Deploy to Netlify'
  inputs:
    authToken: 'Ed-NN2owB9OHvkfqg9MJs5iuoPdEIkPMsnGmfBy7Gag'
    siteId: '$env:netlifySiteId'
    sourceDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'
```

But this task gives an error:

> 2021-04-23T07:51:47.2180471Z [command]C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\Users\alucardu\AppData\Roaming\npm\netlify.cmd deploy "--auth=Ed-NN2owB9OHvkfqg9MJs5iuoPdEIkPMsnGmf***" "--site=$env:netlifySiteId" "--dir=C:\agent_work\r1\a\flexwerker\" --prod "--functions=C:\agent_work\r1\a" --json"
> 2021-04-23T07:51:49.7013050Z  »   Error: Site not found

As you can see in the `--site` value it returns the `$env:netlifySiteId` as a string, and not the value.

Do I need to change the syntax on the variable in the Netlify task or is it not possible to use a variable there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the var syntax was wrong. I changed the var syntax to `$(netlifySiteId)` and now it works.